# Print value if key is matching in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I print the value of two different HashMaps if the key is matching?

```
HashMap<String, String> color = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> fruits = new HashMap<String, String>();

color.put("11", "red");
color.put("14", "blue");
color.put("26", "green");
fruits.put("26", "banana");
fruits.put("11", "apple");
fruits.put("14", "melon");
```

And I would like the result to look like this:

```
"11 : red apple"
"14 : blue melon"
"26 : green banana"
```

My current attempt

```
for(int i=0; i<color.size(); i++){
            if(color.keySet().equals(fruits.keySet())){
                System.out.println("Its a match!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The solution is easy. So easy that I'm not willing to just tell you without first seeing what you've tried and an explanation of what didn't work.

Comment: Your "current attempt" doesn't seem at all to be intended to produce the output that you say is the result you want.

Comment: It looks like you misunderstand `keySet()`. It gives you a set of all the keys of a `HashMap`. So you're on to something. I'll give you an outline: iterate over the `keySet` of any of the two maps. For every key, check if that key also exists in the other map. If so, print the key as well as the values associated with that key from both maps. Done. All you need is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a stream and collect them to a new Map

```
Map<String, String> map = color.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> color.get(e.getKey()) + " " + fruits.get(e.getKey())));
System.out.println(map); // {11=red apple, 14=blue melon, 26=green banana}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> color = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> fruits = new HashMap<String, String>();

    color.put("11", "red");
    color.put("14", "blue");
    color.put("26", "green");
    fruits.put("26", "banana");
    fruits.put("11", "apple");
    fruits.put("14", "melon");
    fruits.put("15", "test");

    Set<String> colorKeys = color.keySet();
    Set<String> fruitsKeys = fruits.keySet();

    colorKeys.retainAll(fruitsKeys); //// colorKeys now contains only elements in both sets

    for (String key : colorKeys) {

        String sColor = color.get(key);
        String sFruit = fruits.get(key);

        System.out.println(String.format("%s : [%s  %s]" , key, sColor, sFruit));

    }
}
```

Output :

```
11 : [red  apple]
14 : [blue  melon]
26 : [green  banana]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function works

```
public void get(Map<String, String> map1, Map<String, String> map2){
    for(Map.Entry m:map1.entrySet())
    {
        for(Map.Entry n:map2.entrySet())
        {
            if(m.getKey()==n.getKey())
            {
                System.out.println(m.getKey()+" : "+m.getValue()+" , "+n.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```